# c# Writing Increasing Numbers in a While to a Database

Tags: c#

Im trying to write "Increasing Numbers/Price" in a While with incrementing in my Database, but still didnt work...

Without a while /incrementing my other code works very well, and i get writed data in my database but with the "while code" not... can anyone help me out? thx you

```
namespace Testing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection con;
            string str;
            string Buyable;
            Buyable = "0";
            int count = 10; 
            double Add = 0.00000000;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                Add = Add + 0.00000005;    
            try
             {
                str = @"..........";
                con = new SqlConnection(str);
                con.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Database connected");
                string query = "INSERT INTO[dbo].[Table]([Price], [Buyable]) VALUES('" + Add + "'," + Buyable + ")";
                SqlCommand ins = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                ins.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("Stored");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {          
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: First thing to do is to remove the empty try/catch. In this way you don't see if you have any error in your sql code. Second point. Tell us the error.

Comment: You need to close your connection in every iteration `ins.ExecuteNonQuery();con.Close();` and this is why you should use `using` statement always.

Comment: Gah. The sql injection vulnerability. It burns us!

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn not really the big problem here, but yes...

Comment: Why does your Add value has `'` around it? Isn't Price a number field? And if Buyable is a string, why *doesn't*  it have `'` around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double Add = 0D; //You really should use a **decimal** for anything to do with money!
    int Buyable = 0;
    int count = 10; 

    string str = @"..........";
    string sql = "INSERT INTO[dbo].[Table]([Price], [Buyable]) VALUES(@Add, @Buyable);";    // + Add + "'," + Buyable + ")";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str))
    using (SqlCommand ins = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        ins.Parameters.Add("@Add", SqlDbType.Float);
        ins.Parameters.Add("@Buyable", SqlDbType.Int); //guessing at parameter type here
        con.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Database connected");

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Add += 0.00000005D;    
            try
            {
                ins.Parameters["@Add"].Value = Add;
                ins.Parameters["@Buyable"].Value = Buyable;
                ins.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Console.WriteLine("Stored");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            { 
                //Do *something* with the exception here!
                Console.WriteLine("Error using the database. The message is:\n{0}", ex.Message);         
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you my friend, but still not work because i get the next error *with ur posted code// ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: Should be better now.

Answer (score 2):

Don't leave the connection open and try to use `using` with all `disposable` objects in your C# life.

```
    str = @"..........";
    using(con = new SqlConnection(str))
    {
        con.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Database connected");
        string query = "INSERT INTO[dbo].[Table]([Price], [Buyable]) VALUES('" + Add + "'," + Buyable + ")";
        SqlCommand ins = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        ins.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("Stored");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: And what about the string passed without quotes?

Comment: @Steve it's numeric. That looks like an int or even smallint column to me. There are other problems with this answer, though. (Perpetuating bad parameter practices is chief, but continuing to force creating new connection objects for each loop iteration isn't good, either.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I like your answer, so I voteup yours.

Comment: Yes it is possible given the fact that he says _without loop it works_ Nevertheless this question is really full of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are writing  con.Open(); in loop without closing previous connection con.Close(); which cause to throw error , write con.Close(); after ins.ExecuteNonQuery(); and try.

Another solution is Open your connection before loop and  close after for loop ends .. I think this may help you